# JasperSoft Studio - How to handle DateTimeOffset

Tags: java, jdbc, timestamp, jasper-reports, datetimeoffset

In SQLserver we have this type *DateTimeOffset* witch the only diferent with *DateTime* is that we have an Offset of the time zone.

JasperSoft Studio (6.3.0 Final) don´t work with this type as you can see:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: microsoft.sql.DateTimeOffset cannot be found by net.sf.jasperreports_6.3.0.final

I can still make it work with the java.sql.Timestamp and apply the timezone of the login.

**Of course I don´t know if this is the best way to work with this data type and I´m open to ideas**

Comment: Are you sure that you can't using *java.util.Date* or *java.sql.Date*? Did you try?

Comment: @AlexK In this case I also need the Time. But for Date scenario it works

Comment: Object of *Date* type contains time and timezone offset :)

Comment: In fact 3 types works properly to this case. But is little disgusting to have that moment when you _read fields_ and recognize the type but can´t work with it.